# Привязать QProgressBar к расчетам

Tags: c++, qt

В программе производится много расчетов в базе данных(сначала исходная таблица разбивается на подтаблицы, после чего в каждой подтаблице производится расчет некоторый полей и на основе всех подтаблиц создается еще одна общая таблица). Все на уровне SQL запросов. Хочется чтобы отображался прогресс этих вычислений.
Можно ли как-нибудь это сделать?

Вот [код](http://pastebin.com/F4epgu1M), выполняющий расчеты, если кому-нибудь пригодится;

Comment: Вам нужно каким-то образом "нотифицировать". Самый простой способ - разбить запросы на мелкие и выполнять каждый по отдельности, а не все одним скопом. Тогда все будет просто.

Comment: Вон у вас цикл `while(_query.next())`. Перед ним посчитайте общее количество результатов, внутри цикла выводите прогресс.

Comment: только если записей больше сотни-другой, то не нужно на каждой итерации обновлять прогресс. Иначе может быть очень долго.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте сигнал

```
void progressChanged(int);
```

И измените функцию так

```
void DataBase::initDataBase()
{
    createMainTable();

    QSqlQuery _query(db);

    QString str_query = "SELECT DISTINCT client FROM input_data";

    if(_query.exec(str_query))
    {
        int percent = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int size = _query.size();

        emit progressChanged(percent);

        while(_query.next())
        {
            QString client = _query.value("client").toString();

            createClientTable(client);
            initClientTable(client);
            addTupleInMainTable(client);

            i++;
            int currentPercent = (int)((double)i/size) * 100);
            if(percent != currentPercent)
            {
                percent != currentPercent;
                emit progressChanged(percent);
            }

        }
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "База данных | Ошибка выгружения уникальных клиентов";
}
```

Сигнал будет вызываться только по изменению процента, а не каждый раз при изменении счетчика.

Comment: `int currentPercent = (int)((double)i/size) * 100);` можно заменить на такой вариант  `int currentPercent = 100 * i /size;` изменение порядка арифметических операций избавит от необходимости делать приведение типов.

Answer (score 0):

Если все производится одним  запросом без возврата управления, это информацие есть только у СУБД. Однако по `query.next()` можно. Можно использовать `QtConcurrentRun::mappedReduced` и возвращающий `QFuture`, величину прогресса которогоможно опрашивать. где-то были стандартные примеры на это